# How to create a variable with double quotes on PHP to post to an API

Tags: api, post, woocommerce

So, i've got stuck in a really simple problem, i'm trying to post a product BUT the variable which in my situation is book pages must be in double quotes when i create the JSON file but it just gives me the number and i can't seem to do it.

What i'm posting:

```
        $data = [
        'name' => $product['description'],
        'sku' => $product['barcode'],
        'type' => 'simple',
        'regular_price' => substr($product['publisher_price'],0,-11),
        'description' => $product['comment'],
        'weight' => substr($product['weight'],0,4),
        'categories' => [
            [
                'id' => 15
            ],
        ],
        'images' => [
            [
                'src' => $product["photo_url"],
                'position' => 0
            ]
            ],
        'attributes' => [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'visible' => true, 
                'position' => 0,
                'variation' => false,
                'options' => [
                    $product['publisher']
                ]
                ],
            [
                'id' => 11,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 1,
                'variation' => false,
                'options' => [
                    substr($product['release_date'], 0, -9)
                ]
                ],
            [
                'id' => 4,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 2,
                'variation' => false,
                'options' => [
                    $product['pages']
                ]
                ],
            [
                'id' => 12,
                'visible' => true, 
                'position' => 3,
                'variation' => false,
                'options' => [
                    $product['dimensions']
                ]
                ],
            ],
    ];
```

The JSON file which is created

```
        "name": "\u039b\u0391\u039c\u03a0\u0395\u03a1\u0391 \u039a\u0391\u0399 \u0391\u03a0\u0391\u039b\u0391: \u0396\u03a9\u0391\u039a\u0399\u0391 \u03a3\u03a4\u039f \u0391\u0393\u03a1\u039f\u039a\u03a4\u0397\u039c\u0391",
    "sku": "9789605027957",
    "type": "simple",
    "regular_price": "5.6000",
    "description": "\u03a0\u03b1\u03c1\u03b1\u03c4\u03ae\u03c1\u03b7\u03c3\u03b5 \u03c4\u03b1 \u03b1\u03b3\u03b1\u03c0\u03b7\u03bc\u03ad\u03bd\u03b1 \u03c3\u03bf\u03c5 \u03b6\u03c9\u03ac\u03ba\u03b9\u03b1 \u03ba\u03b1\u03b9 \u03ac\u03b3\u03b3\u03b9\u03be\u03b5 \u03bc\u03b5 \u03c4\u03b1 \u03c7\u03b5\u03c1\u03ac\u03ba\u03b9\u03b1 \u03c3\u03bf\u03c5 \u03c4\u03bf \u03b1\u03c0\u03b1\u03bb\u03cc \u03c4\u03bf\u03c5\u03c2 \u03c4\u03c1\u03af\u03c7\u03c9\u03bc\u03b1 \u03ba\u03b1\u03b9 \u03c4\u03b9\u03c2 \u03bc\u03bf\u03c5\u03c3\u03bf\u03cd\u03b4\u03b5\u03c2 \u03c4\u03bf\u03c5\u03c2.\r\n\r\n\u0394\u03b5\u03bd \u03b5\u03af\u03bd\u03b1\u03b9 \u03c3\u03b1\u03bd \u03b1\u03bb\u03b7\u03b8\u03b9\u03bd\u03ac;",
    "weight": "0",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 15
        }
    ],
    "images": [
        {
            "src": "",
            "position": 0
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "visible": true,
            "position": 0,
            "variation": false,
            "options": [
                "Susaeta"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "visible": true,
            "position": 1,
            "variation": false,
            "options": [
                "2017-05-22"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "visible": true,
            "position": 2,
            "variation": false,
            "options": [
                "\"12\"" <---- This is wrong
                   12 <------ This is wrong
                  "12" <------- That's what i want
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "visible": true,
            "position": 3,
            "variation": false,
            "options": [
                "15 x 20"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

Adding `'"'.$product['pages'].'"'` doesn't work and `sprintf('"%s"', $product['pages'])` also, it just display the products pages with double quotes when posted i just want the pages number. Can someone please give me the solution to this stupid problem of mine.

Thank you and regards!

Comment: Hi, could you try to reduce this to a [mcve] - rather than the real request, just create an array that has just the "pages" part, and show the _exact_ input, code, actual output, and wanted output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution, i used `strval($product['pages'])` and it worked like a charm.